# Where's my Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I read and re-read the tutorial ([tutorials ubuntu.com](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5)) and I cannot find any mention of shrinking the primary partition before installing Ubuntu.  In fact I believe that it just says that you have either the option of removing the existing operating system or installing along side of it. This led me to believe that I would have a duel boot.

I do not have an option to boot into Windows 10, so I'm worried that I've lost it, because in reading this forum I see that I should have shrunk my Windows partition, which I didn't do.

How can I tell if it's still there? Also, why is the text in Ubuntu so damn small? Some of the programs I've looked at I had to use a magnifying glass.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which option did you choose, remove everything or install along side?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not seeing a dual-boot tutorial at http://tutorials.ubuntu.com. Can you, by chance, provide a link?

Comment: Did you use the "install alongside" option? In that case, it should have detected Windows 10, proposed to resize partitions. Aren't you simply still booting on the Ubuntu install media instead?

Comment: About the font size, do you have a 4K screen? You may need to set up the resolution to a High DPI mode, or simply lower it down somewhat from the system settings.

Comment: @wazoox No no no.... The resolution to use should always be the native resolution. For HiDPI users should change **scaling**.

Comment: As noted on the web-linked tutorial page "Options related to side-by-side installation or erasing a previous installation are only offered when pre-existing installations are detected."

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#5

Comment: It was a little bit confusing, but the tutorial states three options, one of which is to install side by side with Windows. Oh well, I had all of my data backed up with Carbonite and I'm liking Ubuntu so much I don't think I'll ever go back to Windows. Thanks for everyones comments.

Comment: On the font size, I have a standard 15" laptop 1920x1280 res. I'm finding work arounds with settings and zoom. As for the option to install side by side only being available when a preexisting installation is detected, that doesn't make any sense.